# How can I filter into a new data frame conditional on the columns existing in another data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have two dataframes.

`df1`:

```
   Date Bond2 Bond3 Bond5 Bond6 Bond7 Bond8 Bond10 Bond11 Bond12 Bond14 Bond15 Bond16 Bond17
1 41275    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
2 41276    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
3 41277    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
4 41278    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
5 41279    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

`df1`:

```
   Date Bond2 Bond3 Bond4 Bond5 Bond6 Bond7 Bond8 Bond10 Bond11 Bond12 Bond14 Bond16 Bond17 Bond19
1 41275    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
2 41276    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
3 41277    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
4 41278    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

I want to create a new `df3` which is `df1` where all the columns are contained in `df2`, and then a `df4` which is `df2` where all the columns are contained within `df1`.

I was thinking along the lines of `filter(df1, names() %in% names(df2))` or `select(names(df1) %in% names(df2)` but neither works.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible data using ```dput()```

Comment: Hi @Macosso, but I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `intersect` on the column names from 'df1', 'df2' and use that to subset the columns from df1, df2 to create df3, df4 respectively

```
nm1 <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df3 <- df1[nm1]
df4 <- df2[nm1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to tidyr, one way would be:

```
df3 <- df1 %>% select(any_of(names(df2))
df4 <- df2 %>% select(any_of(names(df1))
```

Comment: I think that's more `dplyr` than `tidyr`. ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, however I get the error `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `Bond4`, `Bond19`, `Bond23`, `Bond24`, `Bond25`, etc. don't exist.`

Comment: I just edited the code. `any_of` instead of `all_of` should do. Btw, better if you post a reproducible data set in your question.